# Is the dominating number $\frak d$ regular?

Tags: logic, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

For a poset $(P, \leq)$ we say a subset $C\subseteq P$ is *cofinal* if for all $p\in P$ there is $c\in C$ such that $p\leq c$. We set $$\text{cf}(P,\leq) = \min\{|C|: C\subseteq  P \text{ and } C \text{ is cofinal in } P\}.$$

Let $\omega^\omega$ be the set of all functions $f:\omega\to\omega$ ordered pointwise. Set ${\frak d} = \text{cf}(\omega^\omega)$.

Under $\sf CH$ it is known that ${\frak d} = 2^\omega$ which is regular. But are there other models of $\sf ZFC$ such that $\frak d$ is singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dominating number $\mathfrak d$ is not necessarily regular. You can see in Theorem 2.5 of the reference below that it is consistent for $\mathfrak d$ to be any cardinal greater than or equal to $\mathfrak b$ (which, in turn, *is* regular) and less than or equal to $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$ (which, against what you write in your question, is not necessarily regular).

> [MR2768685](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2768685). Blass, Andreas(1-MI). [*Combinatorial cardinal characteristics of the continuum*](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf). Handbook of set theory. Vols. 1, 2, 3, 395–489, Springer, Dordrecht, 2010.

The argument essentially goes back to Hechler, and Andreas provides references and details.

Comment: What Theorem 2.5 shows is actually more general: Starting with any model of $\mathsf{GCH}$, consider any three cardinals $b\le d\le c$ of the model, with the only restrictions that $b$ is regular and uncountable, and that the cofinality of $c$ is uncountable. There is then a ccc forcing extension (thus, all cardinals and cofinalities are preserved) in which we have that ${\mathfrak b}=b$, ${\mathfrak d}=d$, and ${\mathfrak c} =c$.